# How to downgrade a java application developed in Java 8 to Java 7 or lower

Tags: java, netbeans

I created a java desktop application using net beans in java version 8 environment. The application is running successfully in my machine. But if i try to run the application in a computer which is having java 7 or lower, it is throwing **Unsupported major.minor version 52.0** error. What changes i have to make so that the application runs on other versions without errors? Do i need to develop the whole application again using lower versionof java?

Comment: set compiler level to java7. If you didn't get any errors, just clean and build your project. If you have any errors, you just need to rewrite that in java7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NetBeans:

1. Right click on your project
2. Click on *Properties*
3. Go to *Sources* in the *Properties* window
4. Change *Source/Binary Format* to *JDK 7*
5. Make any changes in your code, necessary to make it compile

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With a bit of luck, you just need to recompile your code with a lower jdk version.

But, if you have used new technologies (Lambda's, ... ), yes, you will need to re-write certain parts of your code.

Comment: If i want to compile the code using lower jdk version, i have to import the whole project into another system running on lower version of java. Am i correct?

Comment: @MaruthiSrinivas No. Just change your compiler settings.